# Handle many realationships in forms

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

Im not sure if i am on the right track, i have a form that goes to create and also edit a model which has a many relationship, but i am having trouble on the method for updating the relationships.

My form has an cotizacion_id=0 when its a new model created so that when updateorcreate is called it wont find it and it will create a new one. the existing ones will actualy have the id.

Is this how I should be doing but have some syntax or am i missing something else?

The error im getting is that it is mixing up what the column names are. in the `DD()` test i get this array.

```
    array:2 [▼
      0 => array:1 [▼
        "id" => "58"
      ]
      1 => array:2 [▼
        "cotizacion" => "15000.00"
        "proveedor_id" => "3"
      ]
    ]
```

And the error i get is on the SQL since its mixing everything up.

```sql
`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '58' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `cotizaciones` where `cotizaciones`.`credito_id` = 105 and `cotizaciones`.`credito_id` is not null and (`58` is null and `15000`.`00` = 3) limit 1)`
```

As you can see im getting as if the coulmn name is 58 instead of id. and the rest too..

CODE

```php
        $postData = $this->validatedData($credito->id);
        
        $cotizacion_id = $postData['cotizacion_id'];
        unset($postData['cotizacion_id']);

        $cotizaciones = $postData['cotizacion'];
        unset($postData['cotizacion']);

        $proveedor_id = $postData['proveedor_id'];
        unset($postData['proveedor_id']);

    $credito = Credito::update($postData);

        $data = [];

        foreach ($cotizaciones as $key => $cotizacion) {
            $data[] = array([
                'id' => $cotizacion_id[$key] ?: 0],
                ['cotizacion' => $cotizacion,
                'proveedor_id' => $proveedor_id[$key]
            ]);
        }

        
        foreach ($data as $cotizacion) {
            //dd($cotizacion);                     //<----------------HERE
            $credito->cotizaciones()->updateOrCreate($cotizacion);
        }
```

Comment: what is the actual error you are getting?

Comment: @chuy edited the question

Comment: your `DD()` and your code is not match like this is correct error

Comment: what? why doesnt it match? thats what i get

Comment: why don't you do the update or create logic in the first loop?

Comment: @Chuy cause i did not think about that, that actually made it work... thx